# amp-social-share type="system" doesn't seem to work on Chrome Android

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to add a native share button on our AMP page with the simpliest code but the button keeps being hidden.

I know my phone + chrome supports the Web Share API as I've already tested the feature on a non-AMP page with regular JS.
I tried looking at amp-by-example but they do not have a real example at hand... only some gifs.
Here's the code they show:

`<amp-social-share type="system"></amp-social-share>`

Does anyone has an actual working `<amp-social-share type="system">` button on a real AMP page where I could see?

Comment: Can you provide a link with the code ?

Comment: @StefanyNewman
here's a link. http://dev.coolibri.de/magazin/open-air-kinos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: You must test your page via `HTTPS` when I changed the url from HTTP to HTTPS I see both icons on my android.

`<amp-social-share type="system"` doesn't work on HTTP sites.

Comment: I've tried to remove everything from my page except the amp-social-share tag, and it didn't work. So I thought something might be wrong inside my head tag.

Then I tried to copy the whole source-code from the amp-by-example page statically.
http://dev.coolibri.de/copy-share.php
The system share button is strangely also hidden.

I isolated it here to have an easier view:
http://dev.coolibri.de/testshare2.php

both tested on chrome android. pages are amp-valid
At this point, I don't see what amp-by-example is doing that it works only on their website.

Comment: Here's another attempt by only using the "get started code" from the AMP doc, and just adding the amp-social-share type="system" tag: http://dev.coolibri.de/simpleshare.html - There's no interference from any meta tag, styling or script... It just won't work.

Comment: @M.Doan I think I got it - you are developing on a `dev` sever thus android devices think the page isn't worth share or they have a clause that prevents them from "sharing" dev pages. AND the URL isn't HTTPS - AMP is very iffy on non HTTPS pages and breaks unexpectedly. 

Test it on your live server ( I assume you are doing a re-design )

Comment: Oh thank you! that was it! hope this will be written somewhere in the AMP docs in the future

Answer (score 0):

There's a [working amp-social-share example on amp.dev](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-social-share/#native-share-dialog-(chrome-on-android)). Note: it'll only work in Chrome on Android.

Comment: Like I said, these are only gifs. no real example.
I can't see any share button on my mobile

Comment: Below the first GIF, there's a code snippet: <amp-social-share type="system"></amp-social-share>. This will show the share icon in supporting browsers.

Comment: alright, now I can see it too. strangely , on our page it is still hidden